# make new docker container after it has been deleted

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

In my Bluemix project, the container has been deleted after migration.

Luckly, the image is still alive so I made a new container using that image, connected my site to that container IP address, set new DB etc.

However, although my bluemix site is up and running it does not show the correct page. It only shows the initial Wordpress site (I'm using wordpress on my site).

Is there something that I should be aware of in this situation?

Thank you

Comment: All the work you do in container will be destroyed when the container is stopped or destroyed. You need to use docker volumes if you want to store your data on the host system. https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 0):

When you run a new container an image is being used as a starting point. If that image has already been pulled to your host it can be used directly, or else it will be pulled from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) automatically.

Then if you start doing work on your container (download libraries, add the source code of your application etc...) this affects only the container and not the image. If you delete the container, that state is lost.

You can save the state of you container as an image that you can later re-use by using `docker commit`. You can also add this image to docker hub with `docker push` and `docker pull` it to other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Containers are by design ephemeral. They're meant to be created and destroyed. If you need a long-running service with persistent data, make sure you use a volume. The volume will store your data across container restarts. Here's a blog post on running Wordpress with a volume in Bluemix that might help - http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2016/01/26/wordpress-on-bluemix-containers-update/